# Variable does not update in module

Tags: verilog, fpga, quartus, test-bench

I'm trying to write a simple Verilog module and a testbench for it on intel's Quartus Prime and checkout it's waveform on Questa FPGA simulator.

The code basically has a clock and a 4-bit counter. The counter should increment at every positive edge of the clock and wrap back to 0 when it reaches the value of 7.

Module:

```
module TFT_LCD_Driver(  
    input clk,
    output reg [3:0] cnt    
);


always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (cnt == 4'd7)
            cnt <= 0;
        else
        cnt <= cnt + 4'd1;
end

endmodule
```

Testbench

```
`define clk_period 20

module TFT_LCD_Driver_tb();

    reg clk;
    wire [3:0] cnt;
    
    TFT_LCD_Driver tft(
        .clk(clk),
        .cnt(cnt)
    );
    
    
    initial begin
        clk = 1'b1;
    end
    
    always #(`clk_period/2) clk = ~clk;

endmodule
```

This is the **wrong** wave form that I am getting.

[image: Wrong wave form]

I tried different ways of writing the code: by setting the initial value of `cnt` using an `initial` block that also did not help and gave me the same waveform with unknown values in the `cnt` variable.

I am expecting the waveform to show incremental values from 0 to 7 at each positive edge of the clock and then wrap back to zero and continue the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `cnt` as a `reg` type, and that type defaults to the unknown value (`x`) at time 0.  At the 1st `posedge clk`, the simulator executes the `cnt <= cnt + 4'd1` assignment, but `cnt` remains at `x`.  This is expected since adding 1 to an unknown value results in an unknown value.  This is why the waveforms always show `x` for `cnt`.

Setting the initial value of `cnt` using an `initial` block works.  Here is one way to do it:

```
module TFT_LCD_Driver(  
    input clk,
    output reg [3:0] cnt    
);

initial cnt = 0;

always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (cnt == 4'd7)
            cnt <= 0;
        else
        cnt <= cnt + 4'd1;
end
endmodule
```

[image]

Here is a demonstration on: [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/WBPD)

---

Using the above approach is fine for simulation, and it may even be fine for an FPGA.  Another approach [is to add a reset input signal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512630/197758)  to your `TFT_LCD_Driver` module and initialize `cnt` in the `always` block.